# Share shiny apps on Shinyapps.io security settings

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I'm new in Shiny and created an app for my company which I want to upload to shinyapps.io and share within my team.

However, this app contains internal information of our company and should be only handled by our team members.

If I upload my shiny app to shinyapps.io and share the link among my colleagues will they only have access to this? Is it possible for anyone outside my company to get access to the app without the link?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By default, if you upload your app to shinyapps.io anyone who has the link will be able to access it.

You can make your app private. Which means that only users who you specify can access it. This does require your users to create a shinyapps.io account, or authorize through Google or Github.

Detailed instructions of how to make an app private and add authorized users can be found here https://rstudio.com/products/shinyapps/shinyapps-io-authentication-authorization/

In general its worth thinking carefully about what data you upload to the cloud. Shiny is probably fine for your company dashboard, but not fine for sensitive patient identifiable data.